# How do I implement a sliding/lagging window?

Tags: r

So I have used `zoo::rollapply()` fairly religiously but I don't think it is appropriate for the problem I am looking at. I have a requirement where I would like to implement a shrinking rolling window. So for example, here's some sample data:

```
v <- data.frame(date=as.Date("2012-1-2") + 0:4, vals=c(1,2,3,4,5))
v
        date vals
1 2012-01-02    1
2 2012-01-03    2
3 2012-01-04    3
4 2012-01-05    4
5 2012-01-06    5
```

I would like the rolling window to go in date descending order so `rev(v$date)` for the order and I would like to sum the vals as follows [lagging by 1 every window] (each row below is a window):

```
5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 15
    4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 10
        3 + 2 + 1 = 6
            2 + 1 = 3
                1 = 1
```

so I expect my data.frame would be:

```
#        date vals new_val
#1 2012-01-02    1       1
#2 2012-01-03    2       3
#3 2012-01-04    3       6
#4 2012-01-05    4      10
#5 2012-01-06    5      15
```

> NOTE: Let's say the above example uses the `sum(x)` function to
>   compute each window. It would be great to generalize this to any
>   `function(x)`. Let's say `function(x) { (min(x) + max(x)) * length(x) * sum(x) }`
>
> NOTE: I would prefer a base R implementation but other packages that
>   might be applicable would be interesting also

Comment: Is there a function that can give me the window so I can apply a custom function?  `cumsum()` does a sum but what if I wanted to do a custom operation on the numbers in the window?

Comment: Not aware of one. There is cumsum, cumprod, cummax, and cummin. Sometimes you can do vector operations before doing the cumsum. So if you wanted a weighted average you could do `cumsum(weight*value)/cumsum(weight)`.

Comment: (If you want an idea how to solve a different cummulative function it might be better to create a reproducible minimal example for that actual question instead of asking how to generalize this question to some other unspecified problem)

Comment: @Henrik, I guess it depends how you look at it. I am thinking my window starts from 1/6/2012 -> 1/2/2012 (5 days of data) and then the window shrinks to 1/5/2016 -> 1/2/2012 (4 days). That's how I was thinking about it. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one using `sapply`

```
v <- data.frame(date=as.Date("2012-1-2") + 0:4, vals=c(1,2,3,4,5))

v <- data.frame(v[order(rev(v$date)), ],
                  "new_val" = sapply(1:nrow(v), function(x) sum(v[order(rev(v$date)), "vals"][x:5])))

> v
        date vals new_val
5 2012-01-06    5      15
4 2012-01-05    4      10
3 2012-01-04    3       6
2 2012-01-03    2       3
1 2012-01-02    1       1
```

Comment: aha, this is great! I have a custom function that I need to run instead of a straight sum so this works!

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
v$new_val <- cumsum(v$vals)
v
#        date vals new_val
#1 2012-01-02    1       1
#2 2012-01-03    2       3
#3 2012-01-04    3       6
#4 2012-01-05    4      10
#5 2012-01-06    5      15
```

Comment: perfect! Just what I was looking for!

Comment: is there a function like `cumsum()` that I can use to apply a custom function to each window?

Comment: @Denis Glad it worked! You might update your question with the expected output because not only me but G.Grothendieck got it wrong.

Comment: @Denis As for your second question: _"is there a function like `cumsum()` that I can use to apply a custom function to each window?_, you might ask a new question and show what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cumsum` and `rev` like this:

```
transform(v, sum = rev(cumsum(vals)))
```

giving:

```
        date vals sum
1 2012-01-02    1  15
2 2012-01-03    2  10
3 2012-01-04    3   6
4 2012-01-05    4   3
5 2012-01-06    5   1
```

or noting that the `width` argument can be a vector (see `?rollapply`):

```
library(zoo)

transform(v, sum = rev(rollapplyr(vals, seq_along(vals), sum)))
```

Comment: problem with this one is that I would like to generalize this to any function. This one seems to be specifically to use `cumsum()`. Would be great to pass the window to some function that I would like to use similar to how `zoo::rollapply()` does it.

Comment: have added rollapplyr solution

Comment: That's what I went with. Didn't know about the seq_along trick for width... Good to know!